# Removing all non-alphanumeric characters from folder

Tags: windows, powershell, command

I am  trying to remove all non-alphanumeric characters from a bunch of Tif files using Windows Command.

I used cmd to access the folder and typed powershell to enter it.

I tried the following line but it did not work: get-childitem *.tif | foreach {rename-item $_ $_.name.replace("^A-Za-z0-9","")}

Answer (score 1):

String replace does not execute regex patterns, you need to directly use Regex. Also using `.Name` instead of `.BaseName` will cause your `.` to be replaced from the tif extension.

```
get-childitem *.tif | ForEach { rename-item $_ ([regex]::Replace($_.BaseName, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "") + $_.Extension)}
```